# Difference between django-environ and python-decouple?

Tags: django, python-decouple

Here I have used `django-environ` to set the environment variable but it is giving me `SECRET_KEY` error.How to properly configure the environmental variable?

I also used the `python-decouple` for this instead of `django-environ` which works fine but didn't work with `django-environ`.

What is the difference between `django-environ` and `python-decouple` which will be the best for this ?

settings

```
import environ
env = environ.Env()

SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = env.bool("DEBUG", False)
```

.env file

```
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = #qoh86ptbe51lg0o#!v1#h(t+g&!4_v7f!ovsl^58bo)g4hqkq #this is the django gives
```

Got this exception while using `django-environ`

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY
>   environment variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`django-environ` works fine, but you need to load the `.env` file – just instantiating an `Env` does not do that:

```
import environ
env = environ.Env()
env.read_env()

SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = env.bool("DEBUG", False)
```

In addition, I've found it an useful idiom to have "sane defaults" based on the DEBUG value (which must only be true when developing):

```
DEBUG = env.bool("DEBUG", False)
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY', default=('insecure' if DEBUG else Env.NOTSET))
```

Setting `Env.NOTSET` as the default will have django-environ complain for unset values.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Env' object has no attribute 'load_envfile' it throws this error

Comment: is there any particular difference between using `python-decouple` and `django-environ`

Comment: Decouple seems to support .ini files for some reason too. Django-environ otoh has useful helpers for e.g. database settings.